# OkHttp response returning null

Tags: android, stream, okhttp

I am trying to use `OKHttp` to get the site content as a `String`. This is my simple `Activity` class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Timer streamMetaDataTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startListeningSite();

    }

    private void startListeningSite() {
        streamMetaDataTimer = new Timer();
        streamMetaDataTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                update();
            }
        }, 500, 1000);
    }

    public void update(){
        SiteContent SC = new SiteContent();
        SC.execute("http://95.173.184.248:9968/");
    }
}
```

And with this class I get the content:

```
public class SiteContent extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(params[0])
                .build();

        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "catch";
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("site content",result);
    }

}
```

This code works fine, for example, for "https://www.nytimes.com/" or any other website but I want to get the content of this website "http://95.173.184.248:9968/". With this website the OKHttp result returns `null` and I am not even sure that it returns `null` because `Log` does not print anything at all without any errors and I do not have any clue.

Is there any protection that blocks OKHttp to retrive the site content or the stream sound creates an error and how can I solve this issue, because with other webpages this code works fine.

The main thing I am trying to achive is to retrieve the listener count.